# Has anyone been able to render a world map visualization in Pygal?

Tags: python, pygal

I've been trying to create a world map using pygal for python. I'm using python 3.9 and pycharms on a mac. I've tried using the code in the link below. Here's part of the code that I copied and tried to execute. When I run it, no errors occur but no file is rendered. The "maps" in "pygal.maps.world.World()" is highlighted and says "Cannot find reference maps in **init**.py".

```
worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
worldmap_chart.title = 'Minimum deaths by capital punishement (source: Amnesty International)'
worldmap_chart.add('In 2012', {
  'af': 14,
  'bd': 1,
  'by': 3,
  'cn': 1000,
  'gm': 9,
  'in': 1,
  'ir': 314,
  'iq': 129,
  'jp': 7,
  'kp': 6,
  'pk': 1,
  'ps': 6,
  'sa': 79,
  'so': 6,
  'sd': 5,
  'tw': 6,
  'ae': 1,
  'us': 43,
  'ye': 28
})
worldmap_chart.render()
```

link: http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to show the map?

You could use `render_in_browser` if you have `lxml` installed.

To do that, replace the last line of your code with this.

```
worldmap_chart.render_in_browser()
```

Here's a list of the other output options http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/output.html.

This is how the map generated by the posted code appears in my browser (Chrome).
[image]

Comment: My original plan was to render the world map as a SVG file such "worldmap_chart.render_to_file("americas.svg")". Nothing happens when I do that. When I replace my last line of code with "worldmap_chart.render_in_browser()" nothing happens either.

Comment: I'm running the code in Pycharms 2020.1.1

Comment: I believe I figured it out. Instead of using Pycharms, I ran it in Spyder and now it works. Thanks for the help!